# SQLAlchemy Как делать выборку с фильтром многие-ко-многим?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Как делать выборку с фильтром многие-ко-многим?
Проблемы возникают с коллекцией.

Сейчас делаю так:

Есть такой запрос:

```
.filter(
            User.city == current_user.city,
            User.propertys.any(Property.name.in_(['Лид', 'Контакт'])), 
            ~User.contacted.any(),
            User.contacted.any(User.id == current_user.id))
```

в котором срабатывает либо `~User.contacted.any()`, отдавая пользователей без друзей, либо же `User.contacted.any(User.id == current_user.id)`,
 отдавая пользователей, у которых друг - юзер по которому идёт выборка, но не работают вместе. Не возвращается ничего.

Один запрос перекрывает другой.

Мне нужно получить всех юзеров, у которых в контактах есть ищущий юзер, и у которых в контактах нету никого, при этом, чтобы они были в одном городе.

```
contacts_users = db.Table('contacts_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('contact_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)

class Address(Base):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    index = db.Column(db.String(50))
    city = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('city.id'))


class City(Base):
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    country = db.Column(db.ForeignKey('country.id'))
    addresses = db.relationship('Address',
        backref=db.backref('city'))

class User(Base, UserMixin):

    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ...
    adresses = db.relationship('Address', secondary=addresses_users,
        backref=db.backref('users'))
    contacts = relationship(
    'User', lambda: contacts_users,
    primaryjoin=lambda: User.id == contacts_users.c.user_id,
    secondaryjoin=lambda: User.id == contacts_users.c.contact_id,
    backref='contacted'
)
```

Не понимаю как правильно делать.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодарю @santavital за наводку.
Запрос я слегка видоизменил но это не меняет сути
Работает так:

```
return (
    self.session.query(
        User
    ).filter(User.city == current_user.city
    ).filter(User.propertys.any(Property.name.in_(['Лид', 'Контакт']))
    ).filter(or_(User.contacted.any(User.id == current_user.id), ~User.contacted.any()))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю что нужно записать условие в одну строку через OR

```
~User.contacted.any() OR
 User.contacted.any(User.id == current_user.id))
```

Comment: Кидает исключение.builtins.TypeError

TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Comment: в sqlalchemy работает or_ и and_ и пишутся они так:
filter(and_(User.contacted.any(User.id == current_user.id), ~User.contacted.any())